# passing value from database to jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i have a list of items from `database` , each having an 'id','image' and 'price'
I am constructing a jquery modal box so that when a user clicks on image of 1st product,the price of 1st product should be shown in dialog box.The images are same for every product.
I am using `php` with `mysql`.
here is my code so far.

```
 echo "<a class='OpenDialog'><img src='pics/phone_2b.png' width='22' height='22'/></a></div>";


echo "<div id='dialog' title='Contact Details'>
        <p>";



echo $row['price'];
        echo "</p>



</div>";
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".OpenDialog").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({ hide: { effect: "clip", duration: 200 } },{ closeOnEscape: true },{ show: { effect: "drop", duration: 100 } },
            {modal: true, height: 200, width: 200 });
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function() { $("#dialog").dialog("close"); });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the error that you are receiving?

Comment: the problem is that the dialog box is showing values sequentially from database irrespective of the image whose id is clicked

Comment: the ID should be unique for each one of your records.

Comment: Why don't you create a function and pass a parameter (id in this case) and then execute your jquery in your function?

Comment: then what to do with that id in jquery function.

Comment: build the dialog? :D but check answer below..

Answer (score 0):

Your ID (#dialog) should be always unique, you just need to add an id to your  tag in your products image, and then in the divs add another id to relate it.

Working BAD example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bJTc/2/) ( What you did )

Working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bJTc/1/)

```
<a class='OpenDialog' id="1"><img src='http://thecybershadow.net/misc/stackoverflow.png' width='32' height='32'/></a>

<a class='OpenDialog' id="2"><img src='http://thecybershadow.net/misc/stackoverflow.png' width='32' height='32'/></a>

<a class='OpenDialog' id="3"><img src='http://thecybershadow.net/misc/stackoverflow.png' width='32' height='32'/></a>

<div class='dialog' id="prod_1" title='Contact Details'>
    <p>Price : 10euros</p>
</div>

<div class='dialog'  id="prod_2" title='Contact Details'>
    <p>Price : 20euros</p>
</div>

<div class='dialog' id="prod_3" title='Contact Details'>
    <p>Price : 30euros</p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".OpenDialog").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $("#prod_"+id).dialog({
            hide: {
                effect: "clip",
                duration: 200
            }
        }, {
            closeOnEscape: true
        }, {
            show: {
                effect: "drop",
                duration: 100
            }
        }, {
            modal: true,
            height: 200,
            width: 200
        });
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("close");
        });
    });

});
```